# Is it okay to save my javascript in a .php format for a wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Instead of putting my javascript into a .js file, I would like to use a .php file so that I can use some php code (for example getting my wordpress blog url, or "if this page" statements).

**Are there any down sides in terms of performance if I do this?**

Comment: Yes, it will ok but that is not proper formatting of wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `.php` page and have your `js` functions within it with the proper `<script></script>` tags, as you said, and there shouldn't be anything wrong with it.

Though, if you have lots of `js` functions that require its own page, then you can pass the values that come from the server-side to the function in the client side. For example.

**in .php page**

```
<script> 
var blogUrl = "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>";

myFunction (blogUrl);

</script>
```

**and in .js page**

```
function myFunction (blogUrl)
{
   alert(blogUrl);
   //do something 
}
```

This way, you can have a proper pure js file, while not making your php files too messy with JavaScript either.

Comment: love your approach to create a variable in the php file however it's not working for me. Nothing come up on the alert. Is this maybe because the script and the php load out of order? I am enqueuing my script properly in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks mate. What are you exactly passing to the function? I did `echo get_bloginfo('url');` as an example, perhaps you should try another variable that you intend to use? try giving it a static value like `echo "test me!"` and see if it alerts properly. Let me know :)

Comment: Still not working for me. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beliy333/s5o5wgej/

Comment: The value you're passing to the function is `blogUrl`, so `alert(blogUrl)` inside the function instead :)

Comment: turns out I had to use it outside of the "function myFunction (blogUrl)" in my js.

Comment: It merely depends on the structure of your code. I am glad you figured it out :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can echo or print your js like so

```
<?php
echo "<script type = \"text/javascript\">
      // code here
      </script>":
?>
```

Remember to escape any characters with a backslash.

OR

```
<?php
//some php here
?>

 <script type = "text/javascript">
//code
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a php file request return javascript content, and have it act as if it were an external javascript file (without the need to write the HTML  tag around it) by setting the Content-type header to a javascript mime type:

example.php:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
?>
alert("<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>");
```

Then you can use this php file as if it were a regular external javascript file:

example.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myserver.com/example.php"></script>
```

In this case looking at the source of the javascript that the php responds with would just contain:

```
alert("www.myserver.com");
```

As far as performance goes, you might have a small hit by processing a php page instead of just serving a static file, but if you add suitable cache layers in front of it it shouldn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily write your javascript code in .php file without using any php tag.
This is totally same as you are writing javascript in HTML. Have to use  tag, which you did not use in .js file.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here, can you provide an example, although there are already a number of answers, does your answer add anything that those don't? If so, make that clear.

Answer (score -1):

Yes can code js inside a php file but, remember to add  tags or else your Script will not function

Scripts are flexible as both external .js file and within a php file in spite of the CMS we use.

Example:

```
<?php
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    // Script code to be embedded 
    </script>
?>
```

Above is the standard Syntax to be followed for integrating Script inside a PHP file.

Comment: You need to put the script tags into an "echo", or that won't work in PHP.